# Redis Message Queue - Auto receive message in NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I am building a nodeJS application. I am using redis message queue. But to receive a new message pushed to the queue I have to call rsmq.receiveMessage method. I want this to be automatic like when a new message is pushed to redis message queue I want the rsmq.receiveMessage called automatically i.e. event based

https://github.com/smrchy/rsmq

Comment: I found redis node module client can do this http://redis.js.org/?_sm_au_=iHHrHDVNnHPSjVQ6#api-publish-subscribe

Comment: Yup. Node redis is what you want. You should add this as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewEisenberg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis [pubsub](https://redis.io/commands/pubsub) can perform this "server push" technique that you describe. You client calls 'subscribe' on the topic or topics it is interested in, and data is 'publish'ed to the topic when data arrives. Your client code would be called with each published payload.

The difference between this an a "proper" message queue (like RabbitMQ) is that

- the data isn't buffered - if your subscribing client isn't listening when the data arrives then the data is missed
- there are no read receipts - in other queuing platforms, a queue item can be marked 'in progress' while a worker is dealing with it. The queue item can be given to another worker after a timeout
- scalability - real message queues allow work to be shared between connected workers: the more workers, the more ways the work is shared. PubSub sends all the data to all the workers

Comment: Thanks @Glynn Bird. I have a doubt on your first point "data isn't buffered". When I use rsmq's receiveMessage in subscriber I am able to get all messages sent by publisher even though the subscriber was not listening when the publisher sent the message. How does that work?